# returning list of sums

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

First off, I am really new to python, and programming in general, and I'm struggling to grasp the concept of nested for loops and nested lists. 
In my code below I am trying to take each list inside the list list1 and sum them using a for loop. I am aware that the range function would help somehow.

Code:

```
def sum_list(list1):
    list_of_sums = []
    total = 0
    for l in list1:
        for value in l:
            total = total + value
            list_of_sums.append(total)
        return list_of_sums
```

Input test:

```
list1 = [[4, 7, 9], [4, 5, 2], [4, 5, 6]]
print(sum_list(list1))
```

Output:

```
[4, 11, 20]
```

Desired output:

```
[20, 11, 15]
```

Comment: Nobody answer. Let's make this a learning moment and go through it step by step.

Comment: first, fix your indentation.

Comment: After `list_of_sums.append(total)`, put `print(l, value, total, list_of_sums)`. This will let you see what is happening and when. You should notice some unusual things.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually indentation alone is 90% of the problem. not re-initializing the `total` is the other 10%.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis exactly. Oh, I'm craving for downvotes today. I should answer that.

Comment: those problems call for list comprehension that avoid all those accumulation errors.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why are you downvoting everyone?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I'm not. but someone surely does. tell that to Alex, he seems pretty concerned by that question.

Comment: I am so that OP can learn properly.

Comment: ok found an exact duplicate. I'm ending all this now.

Comment: @AlexHall We are here to help users by posting the knowledge we have. so that we can learn by sharing. but the way you were downvoting is not good for any poster. Stop discouraging others and if please post what you know.Be a helper before a coder.

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi The way to help here is to guide OP through the solution step by step, where they are involved in each step (unfortunately OP is not responding). If they come up with the solution themselves they gain so much more understanding than if they are shown it. Plus learning how to debug is an essential skill.

Comment: @AlexHall Yes I agree Bro. But Its up-to OP how he can grasp the points. Even we don't have time to spoon feed anyone. Anyway there was not need to discourage anyone by down votes. Hope you can understand.Lets stop this now.Chao!

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi to spoonfeed means to give the answer immediately. According to google it is to "provide (someone) with so much help or information that they do not need to think for themselves."

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using list comprehension, it's one of the best thing provided by python. it really shirnks you code and yet easy to understand. 
following post my help. You can google more on **list comprehension**, if you like

http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

```
def sum_list(list1):
    return [sum(inner_list) for inner_list in list1]

print sum_list([[4, 7, 9], [4, 5, 2], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: that code works. Please explain your code

Comment: They are a beginner in python and need to learn how to use loops. This doesn't help.

Comment: could someone explain, why down vote?

Comment: I did explain. OP said "I'm struggling to grasp the concept of nested for loops and nested lists.", they need to learn how to get past that.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical issues in your code. Think carefully when you should reset total and when to append result to the list_of_sums.

```
def sum_list(list):
    list_of_sums = []
    for sublist in list:
        total = 0
        for value in sublist:
            total += value
        list_of_sums.append(total)
    return list_of_sums
```

Comment: Don't spoonfeed them the answer, they can learn so much more by seeing how to fix the problem themselves.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing when to answer and when to tease. And I created a code that is easy to understand and learn thos nested loops.
I don't have enough points to comment on question and by answering I have one less. Awesome.

Comment: Well 7 people agreed with my comment saying not to answer so there was a pretty good indication. Not everyone had to do the 'teasing', I'd already started the process. If some time from now OP still doesn't respond to comments I will retract my vote. But in case OP still hasn't seen it I would like it if you deleted the answer, that'll recover your points.

Comment: I was answering, while your comment came. So now you want me to delete my answer, because you decided to teach someone (and those 7 persons liked that)? I'll keep my answer for a moment just because I want to comment to this thread.
BTW, do you know that people learn by different ways? Some people also learn by seeing the answer and thinking about how it works. Maybe someone learns by reading those 14 comments below the question - where most comments are about downvoting.

Comment: Everyone *can* learn by reading the answer, but learning how to find the answer yourself is objectively better.

Comment: OK, I can't retract my downvote now unless the answer is edited. I don't think it's worth deleting at this stage unless you want to recover your reputation. BTW, "So now you want me to delete my answer, because you decided to teach someone" - the request may seem crazy to you now, but 4 people did in fact delete their answers immediately after posting, without me saying anything extra.